# wal_level set to replica at database level but i dont see that in configuration file

Tags: postgresql

wal_level is commented in postgresql.conf and i dont see any entry in auto.conf either. but at the databsae level i see its set to REPLICA. Is there any other place whee it could have been set?

```
postgres@postgresqlmaster:/etc/postgresql/12/data$ psql -p 5433
psql (12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# select name, setting, sourcefile, sourceline from pg_settings where name = 'wal_level';
   name    | setting | sourcefile | sourceline
-----------+---------+------------+------------
 wal_level | replica |            |
(1 row)
```

```
postgres@postgresqlmaster:/etc/postgresql/12/data$ cat /var/lib/postgresql/12/data/postgresql.auto.conf
# Do not edit this file manually!
# It will be overwritten by the ALTER SYSTEM command.
listen_addresses = '*'
shared_buffers = '200MB'
synchronous_standby_names = 'pgstandby_synch1'
```

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-SETTINGS) "*The default value is replica*"

Comment: It masy sound dumb but i ll ask away. When it says 'default' shouldnt that be from a configuration file in i general? All the parameters should be mentioned in either the conf or auto.conf file isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replica` is the default value for `wal_level`.

“Default” means the value that is used if the configuration files fail to provide a setting for the parameter. It is a value that is hard coded into the `postgres` executable.

`postgresql.conf` contains most parameters “commented out” and with their default values. This may be confusing at first, but documents both the parameters and their default values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Laurenz.